# Rails 3 recommendations for good javascript tutorials

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am very familiar with javascript and jquery in general, but I am looking for a good guide on how it works in rails 3.0. I understand that the javascript libraries have been rewritten in rails 3. (I never used rails 2.0)

It seems there are no railsguides for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this tutorial useful:

http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/

Answer (score 2):

For Rails tutorials it's often hard to go past Ryan Bates:

- [Intro to js in Rails](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript)
- [Testing JS in rails](http://railscasts.com/episodes/261-testing-javascript-with-jasmine/), same episode [revised for coffeescript](http://railscasts.com/episodes/261-testing-javascript-with-jasmine-revised)
- [Passing data to JS](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript)
- Even [Backbone.js in Rails](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=backbone)

Answer (score 0):

Getting jQuery working in rails 3...

http://joshhuckabee.com/jquery-rails-3

Complete ajax crud with rails 3...

http://www.stjhimy.com/posts/7-creating-a-100-ajax-crud-using-rails-3-and-unobtrusive-javascript